useNavigate inside Router but still throws error
I'm using useNavigate from react-router-dom to redirect users to different pages of website. I'm passing useNavigate as a prop to my Components so I can evaluate it later when user clicks on a button. all of my components are inside a BrowserRouter Component from react-router-dom but it still throws an error. here is my App component:
function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <main dir="rtl" lang="fa">
                <header>
                    <NavBar />
                </header>
                <Routes>
                    <Route index element={<ElectricalPanel onClick={() => navigate("efuse/")} />} />
                    <Route path="duct/" element={<Duct onClick={() => navigate("wiresho/")} />} />
                    <Route path="efuse/" element={<EFuse onClick={() => navigate("duct/")} />} />
                    <Route path="rail/" element={<Rail onClick={() => navigate("shemsh/")} />} />
                    <Route path="screw/" element={<Screw onClick={() => navigate("/")} />} />
                    <Route path="shemsh/" element={<Shemsh onClick={() => navigate("terminal/")} />} />
                    <Route path="slamp/" element={<SignalLamp onClick={() => navigate("screw/")} />} />
                    <Route path="terminal/" element={<Terminal onClick={() => navigate("slamp/")} />} />
                    <Route path="wiresho/" element={<WireSho onClick={() => navigate("rail/")} />} />
                </Routes>
            </main>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

This is one of my components(all components have same/similar handleSubmit functions):
const Screw = ({onClick}) => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(null);
    const handleSubmit = () => {
        onClick();
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>پیچ</h1>
            <div className="fuse-container">
                <div
                    className="fuse-option"
                    onChange={(e) => setCount(parseInt(e.target.value))}
                >
                    <label htmlFor="count">تعداد بسته پیچ را وارد کنید:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="count" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>{count > 0 && <button onClick={handleSubmit}>تایید</button>}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

As you can see I have some Routes inside a Routes component inside a BrowserRouter Component. But it still says my navigate is not inside BrowserRouter.

It's actually the case because you try to call useNavigate inside App component but this component isn't wrapped with BrowserRouter. It should be wrapoed outside. Wrap your App Component with BrowserRouter in your main.js or index.js and remove BrowserRouter from your App component.
Like this:
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

